# Can we use Delphi 7 ADO components to connect and access Oracle 12.X database?

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

Can we use Delphi 7 ADO components to connect and access Oracle 12.X database? I check the MDAC Version it is showing '6.1.7601.17514' on my machine. Can anybody help, How can I use Delphi 7 to access Oracle 12.X database?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long that there is an ODBC driver available...

Comment: I asked this question because some where it was mention that old components especially shipped with Delphi 7 have problem accessing Oracle 11 g and suggested to use new version of Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?

You can connect with OLEDB provider. Try a coonectionstring like this:

> Provider =msdaora; Data Source =MyOracleDB; User Id=myUser; Password=myPsw;